# How to update settings field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an option and a setting field defined:

```
$options = get_option(ISC_PLUGIN_ID .'_options'); 
register_setting(ISC_PLUGIN_ID .'_options',ISC_PLUGIN_ID .'_options',array(ISC_PLUGIN_ID, 'validate'));
add_settings_field("apikey","API Key:", [ISC_PLUGIN_ID,"apikey_default"],ISC_PLUGIN_ID,'plugin_main');
```

How can I update the API key? I have tried:

```
$updated = update_option('apikey', 'default-key');
```

But it returns false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need a form to change, update the field, see the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)

Comment: @bueltge can it be done without a form? i want to update it programaticly

Comment: Yes, however add_settings_field is not necessary. This is an function from the API to get forms, settings areas. You should only work with add_ , get_ , update_option. see https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)

You should use the Settings API only if you  work with forms, display and change the options.

Small hint. The Settings API works only in the single installation mode, not in the [Multisite Mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

### [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)

If you need only a programmatically way to set, change options value use the options API, there is easier to use for this way.

#### Example

```
// Create an option to the database
add_option( $option, $value = , $deprecated = , $autoload = 'yes' );

// Removes option by name.
delete_option( $option );

// Fetch a saved option
get_option( $option, $default = false );

// Update the value of an option that was already added.
update_option( $option, $newvalue );
```